# Inductance in Power cords

Tags: inductance, appliances

Why doesn't the Inductance/Capacitance of Laptop charging wires and other appliances effect the performance of the devices/ power supplies?

An inductance would be introduced if the wires are lying in a loop or mixed together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be a small inductance created by wrapping up a cord in a loop, but the effect will be negligible.  There are two reasons for this.  First, the inductance will be so small that the effect at power line frequency is negligible.  Second, power cords carry both the supply and return so the overall current flowing through the wire is zero, making the impact of any parasitic inductance negligible.  Now, if you took 1000 ft. of wire for your hot and neutral and wrapped them up separately, you would definitely see some effects.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is answered I'd like to say one thing but first the question: -

> Why doesn't the Inductance/Capacitance of Laptop charging wires and other appliances effect the performance of the devices/ power supplies?

For many switch mode power supplies, the inductance and capacitance of the cable DO affect the performance, but in a good way. Switching power supplies create a "a bit of a mess" of the incoming AC voltage supply at their terminals; a lot of high frequency noise is generated and, for many designs, the power cord acts as a filter and reduces this noise to a lower level allowing it to pass EMC regulations.